# redirect wordpress child pages to their parent page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a glossary page in my site with child pages like this:

```
http://my-domain.com/glossay/a/
http://my-domain.com/glossay/b/
http://my-domain.com/glossay/c/
...
```

& every item in glossary has it's own child page based on alphabet like this:

```
http://my-domain.com/glossay/a/abandon/
http://my-domain.com/glossay/a/art/

http://my-domain.com/glossay/b/bee/
...
```

I need a redirection rule to redirect users from items child page, to their  parent page based on their first word.
for example:

```
http://my-domain.com/glossay/a/abandon/
Redirects To: 
http://my-domain.com/glossay/a/

http://my-domain.com/glossay/b/bee/
Redirect to:
http://my-domain.com/glossay/b/
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following .htaccess rule should do the trick:

```
RewriteRule ^glossay/([a-zA-z])/.+$ /glossay/$1 [L,R=302]
```

Basically everything that's after the letter gets truncated and the user is redirected to the parent letter. Note that this rule will also redirect children of children, if any (e.g. /glossay/a/another/children will be also redirected to /glossay/a)